# "You were not connected because a duplicate name exists on the network" Error on Server2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, netbios

I have a Server2003 server which started to have the error in the subject:

System error 52 has occured
"You were not connected because a duplicate name exists on the network."

I get this error when I'm trying to access the server named "FileX" (server 2012) by it's A name record "store" such as "net view //store"

There is an A record on the DNS server "store" which points to the IP address of the FileX server (10.0.150.100).

This happens to be the only server 2003 server, so I can't replicate if this happens in all the servers or not.

"nbtstat -a store" returns "Host not fount" error.

net view //FileX does lists the files, no problems there.

I have tried the following:

Add NetBios name for the server: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/adding-multiple-netbios-names-for-windows-servers/ -> I made this on the FileX server, but did not reboot.

The suggestion provided by MS: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914056 -> Tried it on the Server2003 machine, did not work.

I have tried editing the hosts file, disabling NetBIOS but haven't found a cure yet.

I'm not very familiar with netbios (too old for me) so I'm expecting some help.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a CNAME record to replace the A record. It's been a while since I last encountered this error but I believe this worked in conjunction with the kb914056 fix.

First in DNS create a CNAME record instead of a normal Host(A) record.

Launch your registry editor
Create a new DWORD key in the registry

On the server open regedit and navigate yo:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
```

Create a new DWORD with the following details:

```
 Value name: DisableStrictNameChecking
 Data type: REG_DWORD
 Radix: Decimal
 Value: 1
```

Comment: I did what you've explained but it did not work. Thanks for the response.